# How to aggregate by certain columns and not others in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by

|other|last|first|program|

|cat|Acker|Bob A|

|dog|Acker|Bob|B|

|reptile|Acker|Bob|A|

|cat|Birch|Patty|B|

|bunny|Calhoun|Peter|C|

BECOMES

|other|last|first|program|

|cat|Acker|Bob A|

|dog|Acker|Bob|B|

|cat|Birch|Patty|B|

|bunny|Calhoun|Peter|C|

How do you get the above to work? I'm a sql novice. I'm trying to get a total count of records by one field based on certain values in other fields but not others. In the above Tables, I basically want sql to pull out reptile Acker Bob A, because A is already represented as a program by Bob. But I don't want the following removed for Bob because these programs are represented exactly once:

```
cat Acker   Bob A
dog Acker   Bob B
```

I've tried this but I can't get it to work:

```
SELECT program, total, sum(program) as allTotal
FROM mytable
GROUP BY program
HAVING count(program) <= 1
```

I want my end result to look like this:

program total allTotal

A         2      5

B         1      5

C         1      5

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Also, please tag your question with the RDBMS that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want

```
SELECT program, COUNT(distinct CONCAT(first, last)) AS total, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable) AS allTotal
FROM mytable
GROUP BY program
```

By only counting the distinct CONCAT(first, last) it will not count Bob twice in Program A.

The equivalent for some DBs without `CONCAT`:

```
SELECT program, COUNT(distinct first||last) AS total, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable) AS allTotal
FROM mytable
GROUP BY program
```

Comment: EdmCoff: I'm sorry, I'm using SQLite. CONCAT is not recognized in it.

Comment: @NishleyFagoone I've now added a version that I think will work with SQLite.

Comment: Thank you for making it not count Bob twice. It's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select
    program,
    count(*) total,
    (select count(*) from mytable) all_total
from mytable
group by program
```